# Getting a Network Time Protocol (NTP) time stamp

Tags: c, ntp

gcc (GCC) 4.6.1

I am creating some sdp using RTF 4566 and I want to get the NTP time stamp so that I can use it for the session ID. It is recommended to use the Network Time Protocol (NTP) format timestamp be used to ensure uniqueness.

However, is there any function that will return the ntp time?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I suspect you can just grab an NTP client library to do this. Are you on linux? Is there one in your distro?

Comment: As NTP is quite complex, I would recommend you to sync the computer the program is running on to a NTP server, and just use the local timestamp.

Comment: I thought this might be simple as the NTP is only the seconds from 1900. The reason I wanted to use the NTP as it was recommended by the RTC. I am compiling on Red Hat. I just need to have a unique value. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need NTP? isn't using gettimeofday() or time(NULL) enough for you?

Comment: I am looking in to those functions. So I think I will forget about the NTP if it is too complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is how I solved my problem.

```
/* Get the time in micro seconds to create an unique session id */
time_usec = apr_time_usec(apr_time_now());
apr_snprintf(session_id, MAX_STRING_LEN, "%lu", (unsigned long)time_usec);
```

Hope this helps someone,

Answer (score 2):

The NTP time stamp consists of a 32bit wide value representing the seconds since 1.1.1900 and a 32bit wide value adding a fractional part of value*1/(2^32) seconds to it. 1/(2^32) of a seconds is less then a nano second (233 pico seconds to be exact).

Getting a value of such precision could be achieved using `clock_gettime()`. Anyhow one should use `clock_getres()` to test whether the clocks resolution is high enough to serve valid values.

Answer (score 1):

surely there is a better way to do it but this one should works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h> //gettimeofday()
    int main()
    {
    struct timeval NTP_value;

    gettimeofday(&NTP_value, NULL);

    printf("\nsince January 1, 1970: %ld.%ld s\n", (long int)NTP_value.tv_sec,(long int)NTP_value.tv_usec);
    // that value is since 1970. So you just have to add 70years and 17 days 
    printf("\nsince January 1, 1900: %.6f s\n", (float)NTP_value.tv_sec+ (float)2208988800 + (float)NTP_value.tv_usec/1000000);
    return 0;
    }
```